# UILocalNotification not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

My goal is to send the user local notifications while the app is in the background. I've started testing out local notifications without success. I've tried adding this `[self initializeNotification];` inside a `UIButton` action.

The debugger enters the alarm if but the notification is not showing.

```
-(void) initializeNotification
{
    UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (alarm)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bla");
        alarm.fireDate = nil;
        alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
        alarm.alertBody = @"Test message...";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fire date is interpreted according to the value specified for `timeZone`. If the specified value is nil or is a date in the past, the notification is delivered immediately.
And, when your app is active, the `localNotification` not present, it onley call the `delegate`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

So, if you want see the notification in `MessageCenter`, you must set a `fireDate`

Comment: And not be active! just figured that out. Thanks

Comment: alarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]; Then, press the HomeButton.